# Reset Autonumber in Access Table Automatically

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with an `ID` field, but the number doesn't reset if I delete something. Here's an article I think has the solution to my problem. [Reset Autonumber](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-access/reset-autonumber-in-access-table-automatically/66cbcfed-5cbe-40f6-b939-9aea8bbea2de).

I got the following error when I used the code:

> "Characters found after end of SQL statement"

Clearly this is a rookie mistake but alas, I am a rookie. What is the syntax for making this compatible?

Comment: Just wonder why you want reset the autonumber? You dont need your autonumeric be in a linear sequence.

Comment: Can you please post your SQL statement?

Comment: _Juan Carlos Oropeza_,  I'm trying to update values in my database but instead of the new information replacing the old ones, it is duplicated and I have to go through and delete the old data. The `ID` is my primary key. Since primary keys can't be replicated because they're _unique_, I'm hoping that zeroing the autonumber will prevent the information from being duplicated.

Comment: _FutbolFan_, this is the code I was using:  `ALTER TABLE Your_Table ALTER COLUMN Your_Field COUNTER(1,1)`

Comment: This will not prevent your data from being duplicated. When you are updating your values, you must be inserting new records rather than updating existing. INSERT creates a new ID, UPDATE sets values based on ID.

Comment: You need to figure out why new records are getting created rather than updated. The Autonumber field is not the problem.