# SSIS 2008 : Export SQL Data to Access Database 2010 Table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis

I am creating a new SSIS 2008 ETL report that will read data from a SQL Server and append it to an ACCESS 2010 database table. How can I append records to an existing access table when there is an identity column in the Access table?

My current solution has an OLE DB source with SQL that reads the data. It connects to a data conversion task and then that connects to an OLE DB destination task. The identity field in the access table is named "Id" and it is an autonumber field.

I am able to insert the values using an OLE DB destination when the Access table is empty. The problem has to do with the identity field and when there are already records in the table.

So, the problem is that my Id column always starts at 1, which means I get an error as the engine thinks I am trying to insert a duplicate key.

I created a SQL Task that reads the max ID from the table and stores it into a variable, but now I am stuck trying to figure out how to use this value in my data flow export process.

Will someone please show me how to insert data into an Access DB when there are already records in the table?

Edited for clarity. I have added the SQL that I use to obtain the desired SQL records below. Note that I am NOT including the ID identity field in my SQL:

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(DD,-(DAY(DATEADD(MM,4,GETDATE()))-1),
DATEADD(MM,4,GETDATE())),101))

DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(DD,-(DAY(DATEADD(MM,5,GETDATE()))),
DATEADD(MM,5,GETDATE())),101))

SELECT DISTINCT   
                      ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),PP.LOBCD),'CPP') 'LOB_Name_Product'
                    , POLICYID 'Policy_#'
                    , P.PRODUCERID 'Agent_#'
                    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(14),POLICYEFFDT,101) 'Policy_Eff_Date'
                    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(14),TS.POLICYEXPDT,101) 'Policy_Exp_Date'
                    , CONVERT(NUMERIC(15,2),TS.TERMPREMAMT) 'Inforce_Prem_Sum'
                    , REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(100),REPLACE(REPLACE(N.INSUREDNM,CHAR(10),' '),CHAR(13),'')),',',' ') AS  'Insured_Name'
                    , REPLACE(P.PRODUCERNM1TX,',',' ') AS 'Agent_Name'
                    , PD.PREDSTATECD 'Policy_State'
                    , REPLACE(II.ADDRLINE1TX ,',',' ') AS 'Insured_Address_1'
                    , REPLACE(ISNULL(II.ADDRLINE2TX,''),',',' ') AS 'Insured_Address_2'
                    , II.CITYNM 'Insured_City'
                    , II.STATECD 'Insured_State'
                    , CASE  WHEN LEN(RTRIM(II.ZIPCD)) > 5 THEN (SUBSTRING(II.ZIPCD,1,5) + '-' + SUBSTRING(II.ZIPCD,6,5))
                      ELSE II.ZIPCD
                      END 'Insured_Zip'
                     , REPLACE(P.PRODUCERADDRLINE1TX,',',' ') AS 'Agent_Address_1'
                     , REPLACE(ISNULL(P.PRODUCERADDRLINE2TX,''),',',' ') AS 'Agent_Address_2'
                     ,  P.PRODUCERCITYNM 'Agent_City'
                     , P.STATECD 'Agent_State'
                     ,  CASE  WHEN LEN(RTRIM(P.ZIPCD)) > 5 THEN SUBSTRING(RTRIM(P.ZIPCD),1,5) + '-' + SUBSTRING(RTRIM(P.ZIPCD),6,5)
                        ELSE P.ZIPCD
                        END 'Agent_Zip'  
                    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS 'Upload_Date' 
                    , 'Open' AS 'Status'                    

FROM COPOLICYPOINTER PP

JOIN COTRANSACTIONSUMMARY TS ON TS.SYSTEMASSIGNID = PP.SYSTEMASSIGNID
AND TS.TRANSSEQNO = (   SELECT MAX(TRANSSEQNO) FROM COTRANSACTIONSUMMARY TS2
                                                    WHERE TS2.SYSTEMASSIGNID = TS.SYSTEMASSIGNID)
AND TS.TRANSEFFDT = (       SELECT MAX(TRANSEFFDT) FROM COTRANSACTIONSUMMARY TS2
                                                    WHERE TS2.SYSTEMASSIGNID = TS.SYSTEMASSIGNID)

JOIN COPOLICYDETAIL PD ON TS.SYSTEMASSIGNID = PD.SYSTEMASSIGNID 
AND PD.TRANSSEQNO = (   SELECT MAX(TRANSSEQNO) FROM COPRODUCER PD2
                                                    WHERE PD2.SYSTEMASSIGNID = PD.SYSTEMASSIGNID)

JOIN COPRODUCER P ON P.SYSTEMASSIGNID = TS.SYSTEMASSIGNID 
AND P.TRANSSEQNO = (    SELECT MAX(TRANSSEQNO) FROM COPRODUCER P2
                                                WHERE P2.SYSTEMASSIGNID = P.SYSTEMASSIGNID)

JOIN COINSUREDNAME N ON N.SYSTEMASSIGNID = P.SYSTEMASSIGNID
AND N.TRANSSEQNO = (    SELECT MAX(TRANSSEQNO) FROM COINSUREDNAME N2
                                                WHERE N2.SYSTEMASSIGNID = N.SYSTEMASSIGNID) 

JOIN COINSUREDINFO II ON II.SYSTEMASSIGNID = N.SYSTEMASSIGNID
AND II.TRANSSEQNO = (   SELECT MAX(TRANSSEQNO) FROM COINSUREDINFO I2
                                                WHERE I2.SYSTEMASSIGNID = II.SYSTEMASSIGNID)

WHERE TS.POLICYEXPDT BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
AND PP.CANCEFFDT IS NULL 
AND PD.PREDSTATECD IN ('CT', 'RI', 'GA','NH','NY')

ORDER BY POLICYID
```

The results are linked to a Data Conversion Task.

The Data Conversion Task is then linked to an OLE DB Destination task.

The OLE DB Destination task uses an OLE DB Provider that connects to an Access Database. One of the Tables in this Database is called MasterTable and it has an autonumber field named ID.

I have added screenshots of the entire workflow below.

1. High-level data workflow

[image]

2. OLE DB Destination connection info to Access Database
   [image]

Comment: My understanding is that it's not possible to turn off the autonumbering. Autonumber is a field type in Access, not like an option for an Integer column like in SQL Server.

Comment: Yes sir, thanks for the reply. But there has to be some way of getting the records, adding the current identity value to my SQL and then appending the records to the access table? This can't be the first time this issue has come up. :)

Comment: Even with all that explanation, it is not clear what you are trying to do with the Autonumber field.  1) You do not need to specify an Autonumber field in an INSERT (i.e. append) query.  It will automatically be populated with the next valid number.  2) But if you are trying to put a particular value in that Autonumber field, then why have it as an Autonumber field in the first place?  If the value comes form the SQL Server through the "conversion task", then insert such values into a standard numerical field (e.g. non-autonumber, long).

Comment: @C Perkins, I am not trying to specify the Autonumber. I just want to insert some records into a table. The problem is that when I do this and there are already records in the table, the ID field is always starting out with the value of 1 and the database throws an error because it looks like I am inserting a duplicate key; this is why I want to grab the MAX ID field and use it to somehow seed the ID column for all records in my insert operation. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Sorry it's still not super clear. Why can't you just exclude the autonumber column from your insert?

Comment: @Jacob H, I added my current workflow details. I am not using the autonumber column at all. As I said, I got an error that I was trying to insert duplicate keys so my first reaction was to try and get the latest value of the autonumber field and insert it into a SQL Insert statement. The bottom line is I Need to read in records from a SQL table and add them to an existing Access table.

Comment: That's the part that doesn't make sense. If you aren't inserting the autonumber field how do you get a duplicate key error? You added the select statement to the post, but not your insert. Are you specifying columns  with your insert? If not, try that.

Comment: See [reset-autonumber-seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290938/reset-autonumber-seed) and [Reset Autonumber in Access Table Automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729307/reset-autonumber-in-access-table-automatically) and (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/812718/how-to-reset-an-autonumber-field-value-in-access).  Even though the reasons for the Autonumber reset might be different, the point is that something has been corrupted in the table and it needs to be reset.  First try compact/repair on the database since it's the least work.

Comment: I have added what my workflow looks like. AS you can see there is no defined-Insert statement per se. And I tried compact/repair database and get the same results. It's almost as if the SSIS Package is not getting the most recent autonumber field before doing the Insert.

Comment: Sorry, I see that you tagged the question with SSIS and I missed that.  Hmmm... Sorry, I'm not familiar with SSIS.  Perhaps the links I shared might still help you out, but I can't help much more unless there is a way for you to get the actual statements generated by SSIS for insert.  Best of luck.

Comment: Okay, despite me not being familiar with SSIS in particular, form what your images show, I would focus on "Mappings" and "Error output".  Perhaps there is a problematic mapping into the Autonumber field?  Perhaps you can inspect or direct errors output for more info?

Comment: @ CPerkins, the mappings are fine, they generate no error when the table is empty. The mappings tab is where you select which field from the source gets copied to the destination field. Some fields generate Unicode conversion errors so you have to convert them to a new field that accepts Unicode; then you map the converted field to your destination field instead of the original unconverted one.

Comment: One more hint:  Sorry for slaughtering these comments, but now I do recall using the predecessor to SSIS and I was able to manually specify the SQL command.  Try choosing Data Access Mode: SQL Command where you can manually craft an statement.  Try the Build Query button.  Also, can you open the database directly in Access after an initial insert, just to see if you could manually insert successfully... see  how it behaves in Access?

Comment: One more tidbit of information: Recent versions (I think at least since 2007) of Access ACE/Jet database engine actually does allow values to be inserted into Autonumber fields without any special directive or setting.  The Access UI does not allow this, but it is possible using an INSERT query--also via OLEDB connection. I still suspect that the conversion process is explicitly inserting Autonumber values and so it would work the first time, but it must be resetting the values for each run so that it fails. Rather than finding a way to get Max(ID), I'd focus on suppressing inserts to ID.

Comment: One other solution:  If you can't overcome the Autonumber problem, have the conversion process insert into empty "temporary import" table, then have it run another query that copies those values into the permanent table.  You should be able to craft and specify your own query to do so and add it to the data workflow.  Over and out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do what I need so I am posting the answer here in case it helps anyone else. I will summarize the steps below and then post the code. I am  using SSIS 2008.

I derived this answer from a related answer I found on this site:
[What is the fastest way to insert 100 000 records into an MDB file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850137/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-insert-100-000-records-into-an-mdb-file-in-c-sharp)

1. Create a data flow task
2. In the data flow task, create an OLE Db source with your SQL code. This is the query that will give you the results to put into your Access Table.
3. Once I got the SQL working, I created a data conversion task and converted most of the columns to unicode (except the date columns). Pay attention to the names in the "Output Alias" column of the converter. These are the names you use in the C# script task shown below.
4. Save the results to a recordset destination. When you create the recordset, the "Component Properties" tab has a field named VariableName. Put a variable there. This variable will hold the results of the SQL query. I named mine "rsSourceTable." This variable is what the C# code will read to get our resultset.
5. Once you get the Data Flow task working, create a C# Script Task. I created several variables for use with the script task.

   The read-only variables:
   AccessPath - Holds the path where the Access file is located. 

   rsSourceTable - the variable that holds the results of our data flow task.

   The read/write variables:
   MasterTableRowCount - I use this to make it easy to report the number of files inserted in log files and email tasks.

6. The c# code for the script task is shown below. I did not have to add any references to this.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ST_afd8e3cca5534e51ba5855e82f502e92.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        public void Main()
        {
            OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection();
            try
            {
                string accessPath = Dts.Variables["AccessPath"].Value.ToString();
                string materTableId = Dts.Variables["MasterTableId"].Value.ToString();
                myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + accessPath;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                adapter.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::rsSourceTable"].Value);
                int rowCount = 0;
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    rowCount = dt.Rows.Count;
                    Dts.Variables["MasterTableRowCount"].Value.ToString();
                    myConnection.Open();
                    //1. When building the INSERT statement, remember to enclose column names in square brackets. This prevents errors because Access allows special characters in column names and OLE DB doesn't 
                    //2. Also remember that the order the column names appear in the INSERT statement is important for the code that adds parameters below.
                    //3. To prevent an error, the INSERT statement is first constructed with a ? for each parameter. The parameter is replaced with the
                    //   appropriate column name in the for loop below. 
                    string insertString = "INSERT INTO MasterTable ([LOB_Name_Product], [Policy_#], [Policy_State], [Policy_Eff_Date], [Policy_Exp_Date], [Insured_Name], [Insured_Address_1], ";
                    insertString += "[Insured_Address_2], [Insured_City], [Agent_#], [Agent_Name], [Inforce_Prem_Sum], [Status], [Upload_date], [Insured_Zip], [Insured_State], [Agent_Address_1], [Agent_Address_2], [Agent_City], [Agent_Zip], [Agent_State])";
                    insertString += " Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    OleDbCommand cmmd = new OleDbCommand(insertString, myConnection);
                    if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);  //LOB_Name_Product
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);  //Policy_#
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);  //Policy_State
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.DBDate, 10);     //Policy_Eff_Date
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.DBDate, 10);     //Policy_Exp_Date
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);  //Insured_Name
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);  //Insured_Address_1
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);  //Insured_Address_2
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);  //Insured_City
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);  //Agent_#
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);  //Agent_Name
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Currency, 255);  //Inforce_Prem_Sum
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);  //Status
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date, 10);       //Upload_date
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);  //Insured_Zip
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);  //Insured_State
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);  //Agent_Address_1
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);  //Agent_Address_2
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);  //Agent_City
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);  //Agent_Zip
                        cmmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255);  //Agent_State
                        cmmd.Prepare();
                        OleDbTransaction trans = myConnection.BeginTransaction();
                        cmmd.Transaction = trans;
                        foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            cmmd.Parameters[0].Value = dr["Copy of LOB_Name_Product"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[1].Value = dr["Copy of Policy_#"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[2].Value = dr["Copy of Policy_State"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[3].Value = dr["Policy_Eff_Date"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[4].Value = dr["Policy_Exp_Date"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[5].Value = dr["Copy of Insured_Name"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[6].Value = dr["Copy of Insured_Address_1"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[7].Value = dr["Copy of Insured_Address_2"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[8].Value = dr["Copy of Insured_City"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[9].Value = dr["Copy of Agent_#"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[10].Value = dr["Copy of Agent_Name"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[11].Value = dr["Copy of Inforce_Prem_Sum"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[12].Value = "Open";
                            cmmd.Parameters[13].Value = DateTime.Today.ToString("d");
                            cmmd.Parameters[14].Value = dr["Copy of Insured_Zip"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[15].Value = dr["Copy of Insured_State"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[16].Value = dr["Copy of Agent_Address_1"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[17].Value = dr["Copy of Agent_Address_2"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[18].Value = dr["Copy of Agent_City"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[19].Value = dr["Copy of Agent_Zip"];
                            cmmd.Parameters[20].Value = dr["Copy of Agent_State"];
                            cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        trans.Commit();
                        myConnection.Close();
                        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success; //add logging here for successful operation
                    }
                    else
                        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                }
                else
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success; //add logging here for no records

            }
            catch (OleDbException oleEx)
            {
                myConnection.Close();
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure; //add logging here for unable to connect
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                myConnection.Close();
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure; //add logging here for any other error
            }

        }
    }
}
```